# Matlab Bug -- Matrix Elements Keep Maxing Out

Tags: matlab, scaling

There's a peculiar bug in my code that I can't seem to figure out. For context, I is an image, a matrix, consisting of scaled values from 0 to 255. GetSpatAvg is a function that is not included here. The problem I'm facing is that the elements in ngtdm always max out at 255. When this function finishes, I get the matrix ngtdm back consisting of many many values that are 255. The code is below exactly as it shows on my computer.

```
function ngtdm = getNGTDM(I,d)
    [rowI, colI] = size(I); 
    ngtdm = zeros(256, 1); 
    for r=1+d:rowI-d  
        for c=1+d:colI-d
            term = I(r,c)-getSpatAvg(r,c); 
            ngtdm(I(r,c)+1)=ngtdm(I(r,c)+1)+term; 
        end 
    end
end
```

I isolated a specific value in I, 254, in the code below.

```
function ngtdm = getNGTDM(I,d)
    [rowI, colI] = size(I); 
    ngtdm = zeros(256, 1); 
    for r=1+d:rowI-d  
        for c=1+d:colI-d
            if(I(r,c)==254)
                term = I(r,c)-getSpatAvg(r,c); 
                disp(term); 
                ngtdm(I(r,c)+1)=ngtdm(I(r,c)+1)+term; 
           end 
        end 
    end 
end
```

The variable 'term', in this instance was always 222. There were 369 instances of 222. Therefore the value at ngtdm(255) (254+1=255) should be larger than 255, yet the element still maxed out at 255. When I replace term with 222 as shown below:

```
ngtdm(I(r,c)+1)=ngtdm(I(r,c)+1)+222;
```

I get the correct value, a number larger than 255.

I can't seem to figure out why my element is always maxing out at 255. Could it be something to do with the fact that the values of I are scaled between 0 and 255. I'm pretty positive that getSpatAvg is not the issue because the correct value is being returned.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug - it sounds like you are using a `uint8` datatype. If you convert to a datatype with more bits - e.g. uint16, uint32, single, double, etc - you will not run into this problem. I guess you are working with images, as images read using `imread` are read in as `uint8` by default to save memory. Quickest fix: use `I=double(I);` either at the start of your function, or on the variable I before you put it into the functions.